# how do you type sec^2(0) on a calculator?

Tags: trigonometry, calculator

I press cos^-1 then ^2 then brack (o) but then it comes up with syntax error

Comment: $\cos^{-1}(x)$ does _not_ mean $\big(\!\cos(x)\big)^{-1}=\sec(x)$. (Note that $\cos^2(x)$ _does_ mean $\big(\!\cos(x)\big)^2$. The notation is inconsistent, and there's no real reason for it except for the fact that whoever made up the notation did it in a stupid way.) Instead, $\cos^{-1}(x)$ means $\arccos(x)$, the inverse of $\cos(x)$ (that is, if $\cos(x)=y$, then $\arccos(y)=x$, usually).

Comment: Why are you typing that into a calculator?

Comment: I see a letter "o" rather than a zero there, which seems to be the way some people write an angle value when they don't know how to produce the symbol $\theta$. (Am I right?)

Answer (score 2):

Here is again one of the times to remind everyone of the unfortunate way in which mathematics, and in particular trigonometric functions, are written in today's systems.

$$\cos^{n}(x) = \begin{cases} [\cos(x)]^n & n\neq -1 \\ \arccos(x) & n=-1\end{cases}$$

That is to say, on calculators, and many papers, if you see $\cos^{-1}(x)$ they do *not* mean the multiplicative inverse, $\sec(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$, but instead they mean to say the *inverse function* such that $\cos^{-1}(\cos(x)) = x$.

To avoid ambiguity, it is highly recommended to never write $\cos^{-1}$ and instead either write $\sec, \frac{1}{\cos}$ or $\arccos$ depending on what you intend to use.

(*the other trigonometric functions suffer the same unfortunate ambiguity*)

---

To calculate $\sec^2{x}$ on a graphing calculator, you should have the ability to write strings of functions with parenthesis and the like and can write it as:

$$1 / (\cos(x))^2$$

If you are using a scientific calculator, then you could push the buttons in the following order:  inputnumber for $x$,$~~~~\cos,~~~~x^2,~~~~x^{-1}$

(depending on the model of the calculator either   inputnumber$~~~~\cos$  will give the value for cos(input)  or  you will need to reverse the order of the button presses to  $\cos~~~~~$inputnumber.)

Answer (score 1):

$\cos^{-1}(x)$ does *not* mean $(\cos(x))^{-1}=\sec(x)$.

(Note that $\cos^2(x)$ *does* mean $(\cos(x))^2$. The notation is inconsistent, and there's no real reason for it except for the fact that whoever made up the notation did it in a stupid way.)

Instead, $\cos^{-1}(x)$ means $\arccos(x)$, the inverse of $\cos(x)$ (that is, if $\cos(x)=y$, then $\arccos(y)=x$, usually).

If you want to get $\sec^2(0)$, you should first notice that $\sec^2(0)=\dfrac1{\cos^2(0)}$. I would, then, first get $\cos(0)$, and then press the `x^2` and `1/x` buttons. (Or, on a graphing calculator, I would just type in `1/cos(0)^2` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Hit these keys:

```
cos(0)*cos(0)
=
1/x
```

on a TI-type calc and you will get 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

The correct key sequence depends on what calculator you are using.
Some calculators require a very different key sequence than others for the same calculation.
But a few observations are likely to apply to any calculator.

As an another answer has already pointed out, a key labeled "$\cos^{-1}$"
does *not* perform a secant function.
If there is no key labeled "sec" then you need some combination involving the
"cos" key and the "$1/x$" key if there is one,
or you have to divide $1$ by $\cos \theta$ instead of multiplying by $\sec \theta$, 
or if you just want $\sec \theta$ alone you can divide $1$ by $\cos \theta$.

For the "$^2$" part of $\sec^2 \theta$, most calculators that have an $x^2$ key
require you to compute $\cos\theta$ first, and *then* use the $x^2$ key.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  If you have the old calculators, you don't have a fraction (hate those).  For those, enter <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>(</kbd><kbd>cos(</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>)</kbd><kbd>)</kbd><kbd>^</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>.

For the new calculators (love those), you do <kbd>ALPHA</kbd><kbd>Y=</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd><kbd>ALPHA</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>cos(</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>)</kbd><kbd>)</kbd><kbd>^</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>

Comment: Seems that you love keystrokes. On a prehistoric calculator, $[0]$ $[\cos]$ $[1/x]$ $[x^2]$. On MS Mathematics, $[\sec(]$ $[0]$ $[)]$ $[x^2]$ $[Enter]$.

Comment: Haha, yes.  However, it's not cos(1/x) it's 1/(cosx), because if you think about it, sec(0) should be 1, but cos(1/0) is undefined.

Comment: The sequences I wrote do compute $1/\cos^2(0)$.

Comment: Yeah.  Eventually that's what it's supposed to look like.